# How can i keep the apollo server available when the redis cache(unnecessary) is disconnected?

Tags: node.js, redis, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I use redis in my apollo server for cache the APQ and response, but i find when my redis disconnect, my server is also shutdown, i think the cache is not necessary, server should ignore the redis error and keep working: send the response. But the reality is different from what I thought, I cant find any solution. My cache config is very simple, like:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  cache: new BaseRedisCache({
    client: new Redis({
      host: 'redis-server',
    }),
  }),
  dataSources: () => ({
    moviesAPI: new MoviesAPI(),
  }),
});
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?